# Where can i see the different UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities settings for each iOS device

Tags: ios

UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is used in plist to limit your app to devices with specific capabilities. I'm curious if there is a list out there that shows all the different Apple iOS devices and list the capabilities that they have.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough I asked myself almost the same question this morning. And Wikipedia has just what we are looking for. You'll need to do some translation of the features into the appropriate UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities name.

The link is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices)